# storing multiway data from for loop

Tags: for-loop

I have the following three-way data (I X J X K) for my polymerization system: Z (23x4x3)

```
Z(:,:,1) = [0 6.70 NaN NaN
0.14 5.79 27212.52 17735.36
0.26 5.04 26545.98 17279.95
0.35 4.43 26007.91 16902.22
0.43 3.92 25567.61 16586.18
0.49 3.50 25202.48 16319.65
0.54 3.15 24898.99 16094.87
0.59 2.85 24648.07 15906.19
0.63 2.60 24441.06 15748.28
0.66 2.38 24270.42 15616.51
0.68 2.20 24130.05 15506.90
0.71 2.05 24014.78 15415.87
0.73 1.92 23921.74 15341.59
0.74 1.80 23847.57 15281.63
0.76 1.70 23789.06 15233.54
0.77 1.61 23744.29 15195.99
0.78 1.54 23710.83 15167.01
0.79 1.47 23687.05 15145.38
0.80 1.41 23671.47 15129.72
0.81 1.36 23662.99 15119.14
0.81 1.31 23660.58 15112.77
0.82 1.27 23663.32 15109.86
0.82 1.23 23670.44 15109.74];

Z(:,:,2) = [0 6.70 NaN NaN
0.17 5.63 24826.03 16191.26
0.30 4.80 24198.87 15757.83
0.40 4.14 23720.27 15417.52
0.47 3.61 23347.38 15147.16
0.54 3.19 23058.01 14933.52
0.59 2.85 22836.18 14766.65
0.63 2.57 22667.24 14637.38
0.66 2.34 22539.27 14537.68
0.69 2.15 22445.60 14463.08
0.71 2.00 22379.90 14409.04
0.73 1.87 22336.70 14371.44
0.75 1.76 22311.74 14347.04
0.76 1.66 22301.57 14333.13
0.77 1.58 22303.32 14327.31
0.78 1.51 22314.83 14327.75
0.79 1.45 22334.27 14333.00
0.80 1.40 22360.11 14341.81
0.81 1.36 22391.09 14353.22
0.81 1.32 22426.11 14366.39
0.82 1.28 22464.22 14380.67
0.82 1.25 22504.61 14395.53
0.82 1.23 22546.61 14410.57];

Z(:,:,3) = [0 6.70 NaN NaN
0.19 5.45 22687.71 14805.97
0.34 4.53 22119.24 14408.55
0.44 3.84 21720.37 14120.95
0.52 3.31 21437.68 13912.54
0.58 2.90 21244.60 13766.39
0.63 2.59 21117.60 13667.05
0.66 2.34 21040.03 13602.91
0.69 2.14 21000.70 13565.85
0.72 1.98 20990.89 13549.24
0.73 1.85 21003.53 13547.54
0.75 1.74 21033.19 13556.41
0.76 1.65 21075.85 13572.54
0.77 1.58 21128.37 13593.46
0.78 1.52 21188.17 13617.25
0.79 1.47 21253.16 13642.44
0.80 1.42 21321.69 13668.02
0.80 1.39 21392.34 13693.18
0.81 1.36 21463.83 13717.38
0.81 1.33 21535.27 13740.33
0.81 1.31 21605.87 13761.81
0.82 1.29 21674.84 13781.70
0.82 1.27 21741.68 13799.97];
```

where I is time (y-axis), J is variables (x-axis) and K is batch (z-axis). However, since I want to use this data to do PCA and PLS analysis, I must change this (time x variables x batch) dimension to (batch (I) x variables (J) x time (K)) dimension, means that the new Z is Z(3 x 4 x 23).

To perform this I can extract the first row value from each slab (K dimension) and rearrange them as a new matrix slab using the following command:

```
T1=squeeze(Z(1,:,:))’
```

Thus, I use for loop to get the results for all 23 slabs. But I cant (dont know how to) store the results in workspace except for the last one. The command I used:

```
[I,J,K] = size(Z);
SLAB = zeros(K,J,I); %preallocating the matrix; where I=23,J=4,K=3
for t = 1 : I %here I = 23
slab = squeeze(Z(t,:,:))’; %removing semicolon here I can see the wanted results in command window
SLAB = slab;
end
```

HOpe anyone here can help me on this.
 Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution;

since I know the slab will have size of (K,J,I), so must provide the same format in the for loop:

```
[I,J,K] = size(Z);
SLAB = zeros(K,J,I); %preallocating the matrix; where I=23,J=4,K=3
for t = 1 : I %here I = 23
slab(:,:,t) = squeeze(Z(t,:,:))’; 
end
```